# Where is the "i" icon?

Tags: apple-watch

I'm attempting to manually re-pair my watch with my phone. After reading this [help](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204505) article, I am suppose to tap the info icon (described as an "i"), but I cannot find it on my watch home screen. Where does this button live?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the illustration on the [Help page in Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204505) you will see a picture of the watch face.  The 'Info' Icon should be at the top right corner.

**EDIT**: Pairing the watch only needs to be done if a reset is needed.  If you stray too far from you iPhone or it is otherwise disconnected, it will reconnect when both are again on and in range.  Be sure to keep Bluetooth turned on your phone.  For more information, see the **[User's Guide](https://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/apple_watch_user_guide.pdf)**.

[image: Info button]

Comment: It was not clear to me that these steps required me to reset the watch back to factory. Thanks.

Comment: All of the settings are stored on your iPhone.  So re-pairing moves the data back.  Your phone should have a backup of your settings. -If this answers your question, please mark it for others. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first reset the apple watch to get the "i" icon.